# How to automate S3 http url permission grant

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

I have a url (in the form of https://s3.amazonaws.com/...) pointing to a file in S3 and I want to have it downloadable by a user so I set the permission from S3 dashboard in AWS console but I learned that it is being reset whenever the file is re-written (the filename remains the same).

Is there a way to automatically set the permission right after the file creation? I looked at boto library but couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have control over how the file is being written to S3?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to upload it.

Comment: @tedder42 it is not that easy unfortunately. We have a Python class doing that which is based on boto library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common operation.

[With the Boto library, you can set an ACL](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/gs.html?highlight=set_acl#boto.gs.key.Key.set_acl). Assuming you have a Key:

```
key.set_acl('public-read')
```

If you don't have a Key, you'll need to have a Bucket:

```
bucket.set_acl('public-read', 'path/to/key')
```

You can use non-canned ACLs also. The documentation links through to that.

In boto3, you can also set an ACL.

[Bucket syntax:](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_bucket_acl)

```
s3client.put_bucket_acl(ACL='public-read', Bucket='bucketname')
```

[Key syntax:](https://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_acl)

```
s3client.put_object_acl(ACL='public-read', Bucket='bucketname', Key='path/to/key')
```

Non-canned ACLs are a little easier in boto3.